# Disable landscape expansion in UISplitViewController on iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

iPhones with big screen(Plus/Max family) have such a feature that when you rotate the device to the landscape mode then UI becomes the same as on iPads - you have master in the left and detailed on the right. Is there a way to disable this feature only on iPhones? I mean if I'll put my iPhone to landscape mode then the UI will stay the same(split view controller won't expand). I tried to to use `splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden` but in this case the detailed with controller doesn't have a back button and you're basically stuck since you cannot navigate back. Thank you

Comment: btw, forgot to mention - my initial view controller is SplitViewController. So, `overrideTraitCollection` will not work since it can only override class size for child vc

Comment: Don't know if what you're asking is possible, but you could just skip using the split view controller on phones completely. And directly set the navigation controller as the root of your navigation flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `overrideTraitCollection(forChild:)` method:

```
override func overrideTraitCollection(forChild childViewController: UIViewController) -> UITraitCollection? {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .pad {
        return UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)
    } else {
        return super.traitCollection
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, just tried it. Unfortunately the result is the same